# React router access params in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-hooks

I am trying to learn using TypeScript in my React projects but I am encountering issues with using React Router `useParams()`.

I import it like this:

```js
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'; // import useParams
```

And I used to access a specific url parameter like this in JavaScript:

```js
const params = useParams();
console.log(params.gameId); // trying to access parameter gameId
```

But now with TypeScript I get the error message: *Property 'gameId' does not exist on type '{}'*.

The error message might seem obvious but I can't immediately find a solution, should I be accessing another property or was I already doing something wrong in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use generics:

```
interface IParams {
  gameId: string
}
const params = useParams<IParams>();
```

OR

```
const params = useParams<{ gameId: string }>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Add proper typings:

```
const params = useParams<{ gameId: string }>();
```